# Why cant i close Alert popup?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**1. Why cant i close Alert popup?**

2. I have tried alert etc, it closes the popup but then i get the odd test where the popup dosnt close/

**3. My Code:**

```
    public void closeAlertPopupBox() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    try {
        Alert alert = this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            alert.accept();
            System.out.println("The popup has been successfully closed");
    } catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
        Alert alert = this.driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to close the popup");
        Assert.assertFalse(true, "Unable to close the popup, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

4. The above code works but i get the odd popup which wont close and there will fail the test .
5. Using the following desired capabilities works, but then I get an error on TestNG which says there was an 'Unexpected popup' but the code still acepts and closes the popup.
6. My Code:

   ```
                   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);

               DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
               LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
               logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
               UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
               caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
               webdriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
   ```

Any Ideas to find a work around this issue? 
[image]
Thanks for you help

Comment: for some weird reason on the 3rd execution the test will fail

Comment: Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept(); or alert.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

As you are only accepting the popup.To close the popup we have to use dismiss method of alert 
Please follow the below code for detail

```
Alert alert= driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.dismiss();
```

If problem remains then you can try  to handle the same i.e

```
Alert alert= driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(500)
alert.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is just to disable popup as the start of the driver session. I mean you need to call the next script inside the current browser context (e.g. `executeScript` - depends on the framework):

```js
document.alert = window.alert = alert = () => {};
```